# configure Scapy to listen for a specific packet and once the packet is received, send a specific packet

Tags: scapy

Is it possible to configure Scapy to listen for network traffic and send a crafted packet once a packet with certain parameters is received? I mean for example Scapy listens network traffic on eth0 and in case an ICMP "echo request" packet from source IP 10.10.44.3 is received, Scapy sends an TCP SYN packet to port 34 to IP address 192.168.2.1 using 8.8.8.8 as a source. Is such setup possible with Scapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Using the `sniff()` function, you can provide a parameter to the `stop_filter` option.

```
>>> print sniff.__doc__
Sniff packets
sniff([count=0,] [prn=None,] [store=1,] [offline=None,] [lfilter=None,] + 
      L2ListenSocket args) -> list of packets

...clipped...

stop_filter: python function applied to each packet to determine
             if we have to stop the capture after this packet
             ex: stop_filter = lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP)
```

If the function returns 1, sniff will stop, and you can continue with whatever logic you wish.

Comment: As I understand, I can specify a Python lambda function to `stop_filter` option. What are the possible Python lambda functions I can specify? I know that `stop_filter=lambda x: x.summary()` works or `stop_filter=lambda x: x.show()` works, but what are the other possibilities? As I would like to send a reply directly, then something like `stop_filter=lambda x: x.send(IP(src="8.8.8.8", dst="192.168.2.1"))` would be perfect I guess.

Comment: You can create and specify a regular function, doesn't need to be lambda.

Comment: I think I stick to lambda functions as those seem to be simpler. However, is it possible to do something like `stop_filter=lambda x: x.send(IP(src="8.8.8.8", dst="192.168.2.1")/ICMP)`?

Comment: It would be better to use the `stop_filer` as the developer intended, to stop sniffing, then follow through whatever logic you wish to use.