# Scapy: receive and then send a L2 packet?

Tags: scapy

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is nice, you have the `srp()` function that sends and waits for an answer.

I am looking for a nice way to wait for a packet, then send an answer right away.

Using `sniff(prn=callback)`, where I send packet in the `callback` function does not seem to work properly as `sniff()` returns the sent packet (probably something to do with the low-level socket).

I also notice if I do a `sniff()` with a `count=1` and send the answer on return of `sniff()` I lose some packets while `sniff()` is not called.

For example, this code:

```
from scapy.all import *
i = "eth3"

def cb(rx_pkt):
    rx_pkt.summary()
    dst_addr = rx_pkt[0].src
    answer = Ether(src="00:24:81:7f:cc:4f",dst=dst_addr)/IP()/ICMP()
    sendp(answer,iface=i)

  sniff(iface=i,timeout=1000,prn=cb)
```

The first time `cb()` is called, the expected packet is sent properly. But after it seems to process its own sent packets.

Is there a better way to acheive this?

Comment: Nice question, but does not cover the requirements I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461555/configure-scapy-to-listen-for-a-specific-packet-and-once-the-packet-is-received?rq=1

Comment: Why does it seem that all but the first invocation of `cb()` are invalid? What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: A network trace on eth3 displays ethernet packet with source and destination address being identical. Those packets are loaded with ICMP() layers. 
 
I expect that for each packet sniffed, exactly one ICMP packet gets sent back to the sender at the L2 level.

Comment: Can you attach an excerpt of the network trace?

Comment: Here a base64 of the trace, after being triggered by a DHCP request: http://pastebin.com/Fx1R5M2v

Comment: I think the problem is that when using `IP()` with no arguments the destination address is set to `127.0.0.1` so each packet the callback sends is immediately received and processed by the same callback, triggering the next packet to send, and so on, in an endless loop.